# Assetic:dump on AWS

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, assetic

I'm trying to deploy my Symfony2 app on AWS Beanstalk. I've managed to get almost everything working except for dumping assets. The eb provisioning script runs fine, but the files are not present when I ssh into the ec2 instance. Here is the deployment log:

```
2015-01-21 14:12:34,414 [DEBUG] Running command 05_update_assets
2015-01-21 14:12:34,414 [DEBUG] Generating defaults for command 05_update_assets <<<

2015-01-21 14:12:35,027 [DEBUG] No test for command 05_update_assets
2015-01-21 14:12:37,870 [INFO] Command 05_update_assets succeeded
2015-01-21 14:12:37,871 [DEBUG] Command 05_update_assets output: Dumping all dev assets.
Debug mode is off.

14:12:36 [file+] /var/app/current/app/../web/css/2f21d5e.css
14:12:36 [file+] /var/app/current/app/../web/js/b21b935.js
14:12:36 [file+] /var/app/current/app/../web/js/2031a90.js
14:12:36 [file+] /var/app/current/app/../web/css/92da39d.css
14:12:36 [file+] /var/app/current/app/../web/css/b5828a3.css
14:12:37 [file+] /var/app/current/app/../web/js/31db152.js
```

Any ideas what could cause this?

#### Update

I managed to run it via ssh with sudo. Any ideas why the files weren't created without it? Does someone know a better solution (since sudo can generate permission problems in the future)?

#### Update 2

I added additional config command which ls'es var/app/current/web and the files exist. Except that when the deployment finishes, they no longer do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved. Elastic Beanstalk runs all the commands in the ondeck folder, then if there were no errors, moves everything to current folder. Assetic was generating files in the current folder, which then was overwritten by the ondeck content.